# How to aggregate gradients in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, mpi, data-science, mpi4py

I have been using a combination of mpi4py and pytorch to try to combine the gradients of multiple instances of the same model. When each model is done its epoch, it executes this code to try and combine the gradients on one model and then send its updated model back to the other processes:

```
on client node:

    grads = []
    for param in model.parameters():
        grads.append(param.grad)
    comm.gather(grads, root = 0)
    model = comm.bcast(model, root = 0)

on server node:

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    for param in model.parameters():
        grads.append(param.grad)
    newGrads = comm.gather(grads, root = 0)
    for i in range(1, len(newGrads))
        newGrads += newGrads[i]
    for param, grad, in zip(model.parameters(), result):
        param.grad = grad/comm.Get_size()
    optimizer.step()
    comm.bcast(model, root=0)
```

When the models run, however, the accuracy stays the same throughout the epochs. I was wondering if there's another way to do what I am trying to do or if the logic of my code is wrong and what I should do to fix it. Thank you all for your time! I really appreciate it!